# Dropdown list is bottom of the site

Tags: javascript, symfony, jquery-select2, sylius

I have a little problem with my select2 display.
The request work perfectly, I've got the right items, the problem is not here, the problem is the list is completely bottom of the site (after the footer).

the code is :

```
<input type="hidden" class="select2 form-control" id="select2" placeholder="search ..." name="q" value="{{ searchTerm ?: '' }}">
```

and :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function format(product) {
        return '<img src="/media/images/'+product.image+'" alt="" class="imgmedia-object" height="60" width="60"/><h5>'+product.name</h5><hr>';
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Get this orders sku
        var skus = [];
        $('.sku').each(function(){
            skus.push($(this).text().trim());
        });

        $(".select2").select2({
            multiple: true,
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('sylius_backend_product_find') }}",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        criteria: {
                            sku: term
                        }
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            },
            formatResult: format
        }).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
            window.location = e.choice.url;
        });

    });
</script>
```

And I have a warning when I search terms :

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

The problem probably come from the warning, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

It was simply because I didn't add the 'bundles/syliusweb/css/select2.css' line ...